# MinGW-w64 installed on Win10 but "make" doesn't work?

Tags: c++, makefile, mingw-w64

On a Win10 machine I've got MinGW-w64 installed and with these files...

- main.cpp
- demo.h
- demo.cpp
  in a directory I can run...

> g++ main.cpp demo.cpp

from the command line and it compiles just fine.

But when I try and create a makefile and run it from the command line by typing...

> make

I get... 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I thought "make" came with MinGW-w64 but I guess not...

How can I get "make" to run on my Win10 PC?

Here is my "make" file saved in the same folder as a text file named "make": with no extension.

```
output main.o demo.output
    G++ main.o demo.o -o output
    
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp
    
demo.o: demo.cpp
    g++ -c demo.cpp
    
clean;
    rm *.o output
```

Comment: There's a dozen different MinGW distributions you can install, which one are you using? I know that at least [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) lets you install `make`.

Comment: Try using `mingw32-make`

Comment: MSYS2 also provides an impressive collection of tools and prebuilt libraries that can save you an insane amount of time. At this point in time you're handicapping yourself if you must use a GNU-based toolchain on Windows and use anything else.